# Audit history for changes in Db Row

Tags: c#, .net, database, design-patterns

***Scenario:***

I have a database table, any changes on data of any column of this table needs to be audit logged for comparison purposes.

***What I have tried:***

I have a history table with the same values columns as the parent table and any change to the database gets recorded into the new table using triggers and I eventually achieve what I want.

***Problem***

The issue is multi-fold:

- I am using triggers which I do not want to use.
- If I have to have audit comparison for n more tables, then I need to have one history table per parent table and which just swells my database and makes it bulky with so many tables.

Is there a better approach of achieving this, please suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer strongly relates to where you *business* or *domain* logic sits.

If your business logic is within your database (`stored procedures` and `triggers`) then, then I feel your approach is correct to have the database `triggers` write to the relevant audit tables.

> I am using triggers which I do not want to use.

**Audit Appoach:**

If your domain logic is in a *domain layer* within your `c#` code, then you're quite right in saying you don't want your audits to be in `triggers`. Mixing business logic between your *domain layer* and *database* may lead to maintenance nightmare o_O

Assuming you're logic is in a *domain layer*: An idea would be to have a `base class` for your domains or services which handles writing to audit trails:

```
public class DomainBase<T>
{
    public DomainBase(bool isAuditEnabled)
    {
        this.IsAuditEnabled = isAuditEnabled;
    }
    public bool IsAuditEnabled { get; set; }

    public void AddNew(T newEntity)
    {
        // default code for adding an entity
        this.Audit_Create(newEntity);
    }

    public void Audit_Create(T newEntity)
    {
        if (IsAuditEnabled)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Your `base class` can have standard `AddNew`, `Update`, `Delete` methods which in turn each call the relevant Audit methods. Then also having you might want to consider an `IsAuditEnabled` switch to allow you to easily turn on/off specific audits. This way you only audit the changes you care about and nothing else.

Each custom *domain* method can opt to write to the audit trail or not. This is also why it's **not** a good idea in your scenario to put audit trails in the `DAL` (Data Access Layer), since *business logic* decides *if* and *what* must be audited and the `DAL` should not have to make these type of logic decisions.

> If I have to have audit comparison for n more tables, then I need to
>   have one history table per parent table and which just swells my
>   database and makes it bulky with so many tables.

**Size of database concern**

1. As mentioned already, only auditing what you need will decrease the amount of 
   audit data written.
2. If the audit data is too much or grows too fast, you could opt for a **separate audit database**. That way your **production database** stays lightweight and optimized and you only can for *rare* cases (hopefully) query the audit database. This way you can go **BIG** and audit the life out of everything that moves without being concerned about performance (don't even include `indexes` in the audit database to allow quick and efficient writes).
3. Also if you don't really care about ALL data in a table, you can create audit tables with only the fields which are **important** to you. So you may end up with a table of 50 columns only auditing 5 or 10 columns which are crucially for historic purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My architecture is that I have Services > Business Logic > Repository > Data/Entities (EF Db First) > Database. I am assuming the DomainBase is the repository in my situation. And I would have the Audit_Create will be a method in it. 

What should be my DB design for this be, should I still have one history table per table or one table to rule them all?

Comment: @Immortal, The `base class` I'm referring to would be in your *Business Logic* layer. From my experience 1 table per audit worked well, as it's maintainable when tables change. Also we were able to go as far have functionality which could *restore* the system from any certain point in history (rebuilding from Audit Trail). Option 2 in my answer to separate database worked well. Database was responsive, lightweight, whilst still auditing the life out of everything that moves to another database.